# Express Route (Optional parameters)

Tags: regex, express, parameters, routes

I have a problem getting my route to work. I have based the route organisation on : [Organizing your app routes with the Express 4 Router](http://www.terlici.com/2014/09/29/express-router.html)

Here is `app.js`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

express.use('/object-settings', require("./route/object-settings");
express.use('/object-settings-edit', require("./route/object-settings-edit");
```

Now the file **object-settings**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Send home page of this section
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the **object-settings-edit** (Please read the comments, the problem is described here) :

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    // Return page for editing object having the ID parameters
});

router.get('/getPageData', function (req, res) {

    // If I'm calling one of those route : 
    //     - /object-edit/getPageData
    //     - /object-edit/getPageData?id=4
    // this route will never be reached ! 
    // This is the preceding one that catch the request. I think I'm understand why, because 
    // any parameters (including the name getPageData) will be catch by the :ìd ? 
  
    // How can I avoid that ? Forcing the id parameter to be a NUMBER only using regex ? 
    // Or maybe there a better way to do it ?
  
    // Return JSon page data 
    var objectID = req.param("id")
    var databaseObject = database.find(objectID);
    res.json(databaseObject);
 
});

module.exports = router;
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`express.Router()` creates a new router each time; it's not shared via the `express.Router()` call.  Doing this won't work as you seem to expect:

```
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/object-settings', router);
router = express.Router();
router.get('/:id', cb);
```

Instead, just do:

```
var router = express.Router();
// Can be done in either order
router.get('/:id', cb);
app.use('/object-settings', router);
```

Just make sure you are referencing the same router object.

Comment: Hi,

I made a copy error while writing my post yesterday, sorry :( I've update the main post with the correct code, please review the first code block.

Could you tell me if the new code block is having the same problem as you said ?

Comment: @erakis instead of `express.use` what about `app = express()` and `app.use`?