# Express route parameters vs HTTP query parameters

Tags: express, parameters, routes, optional-parameters

I had always been wondering what kind of notation is the following,

`GET /user/:name/books/:title`

and how to interpret it until recently, when I learned that they are in the form of Express route and the ones with `":"` are Express route parameters.

So here comes the question that I didn't find the answers from, say,

- [Express Route (Optional parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218770/)
- [Express default route parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136788/)

The question is, what if most or even all parameters are optional? How to handle that with Express route?

The problem is, with HTTP query parameters, like

`https://example.org/?page=2&limit=3&sort=price`

The order of query parameters can be arbitrary, whereas for Express route it seems to me the route parameters has to be specified in a very rigid way/order. So what if all route parameters are optional, and I just need to specify the last one? (no matter how you arrange the route parameters orders, there will always be a last one)

I did learn that Express can deal with `querystring.parse(parsedUrl.query)`, but the reason I'm asking this question is really because of this -- https://github.com/gofiber/docs/blob/master/original/routing.md#parameters

I.e., gofiber follows/uses Express routing convention to handle route parameters, and I need all route parameters to be optional.

How to deal with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every variable you send in URL with `:` is recieved in with [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name, then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object defaults to {}.

```js
// will be available in route in req.params object
router.get('/somepath/with/:variable', (req ,res) => {
  console.log(req.params.variable);
});
```

Every variable you send in URL after `?` (query params) will be available in [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

> This property is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. When query parser is set to disabled, it is an empty object {}, otherwise it is the result of the configured query parser.

```js
// will be available in route in req.query object
router.get('/somepath/with/variables?page=2&limit=3&sort=price', (req ,res) => {
  console.log(req.query.page);
  console.log(req.query.limit);
  console.log(req.query.sort);
});
```

every data you send through ajax or forms or something of the sort will be recieved with [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

```js
// will be available in route in req.body object
router.get('/somepath/with/variables', (req ,res) => {
  // send in request body like for example form data:
  console.log(req.body.variable1) // i.e
});
```

This are three objects that collect data in three different ways.
You should just choose what's right for your sceneraio. I guess Route params isn't the right option and you should go with `req.query` when variables arrive randomly but you should know how to handle them once you have them parsed in the corresponding object.

I hope i understood the question and clarified.

Comment: _"I guess Route params isn't the right option and you should go with req.query when variables arrive randomly"_ So indeed the route params isn't the right option for my case. Thanks for the confirmation and the detailed explanation!