# Give back answers from backend based on inputs from frontend

Tags: typescript, svelte, deno

I want to give back an answer form the backend to the frontend whenever "Hallo" is given as an input form the frontend, if the input is not "Hallo" nothing should be given back

```
import { opine } from "https://deno.land/x/opine@2.1.1/mod.ts";
import { opineCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
const app = opine();
app.use(opineCors())

app.get("/gibmirdieloesung", function (req, res) {
    console.log(require("Hallo").inspect(req.params))
    res.send({ answer: "This is an example" });
});

app.listen(
    3004,
    () => console.log("server has started on http://localhost:3004 "),
);
```

Is the usage of require() correct? If not, do you have any suggestions?

Thank U

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205191/express-route-parameters-vs-http-query-parameters check the solution

Comment: What do you mean by "input from the frontend"?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. Hmm Basically I was trying to set up a web-app. This is the code for the backend. It recorgnizes inputs from the web-app and gives back answers oder solutions. In this case "This is an example".  We managed to solve this problem by analysing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205191/express-route-parameters-vs-http-query-parameters. Nervertheless, thank you :)

Comment: I supposed you form submit using GET method thus my answer. Funny 'gibmirdieloesung` which was to long to type `gib mir die loesung` (de_DE).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `require` and `inspect` and changed the response a little.

Now when requesting `http://localhost:3004/hello?a=1&b=2` using the code below

```js
#!/usr/bin/env deno run --allow-read --allow-net

import { opine } from "https://deno.land/x/opine@2.1.1/mod.ts";
import { opineCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
const app = opine();
app.use(opineCors())

app.get("/hello", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    let r = req.query;
    r.answer = "This is an example";
    res.send(r);
});

app.listen(
    3004,
    () => console.log("server has started on http://localhost:3004 "),
);
```

I get `{"a":"1","b":"2","answer":"This is an example"}` as a response.